# Translating an an 'on.click' event in PHP, from 'window.open' to a basic URL link

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, onclick, window.open

I'm trying to perform a hack on a Joomla component to better suit my needs. The current code looks like this:

```
$eventprnt = 'onclick="window.open(\'index.php?option=com_coupon&view=coupons&task=print_coupon&id='.$item->id.'\')" ';
$eventcart = ' onclick="add_to_cart('.$item->id.');"';
$live_prt = 'coupon_print';$live_crt = 'coupon_cart';
if($item->coupon_type == 4){
    $dealevent = 'onclick="prompt_link('.$item->id.','.$final_price.',this)"';
}
```

The `$eventprnt` function currently opens a browser window. I would like to convert this to a standard URL Link whilst retaining the `onclick` event (ie: Not swapping to `echo` with `<a>` or using a JScript `<button>` (There are multiple calls, already attached to this trigger).

I've tried everything, the syntax is killing me. - I've tried `window.location` instead of `window.open`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

location is the way to go:

```
$eventprnt = 'onclick="location.href=\'index.php?option=com_coupon&view=coupons&task=print_coupon&id='.$item->id.'\';" ';
```